# How can I POST json data to a WCF web service?

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest

I have the following method on a wcf web service.

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public void UpdateAnalysisParameters(string parameterSets)
    {
       //....
    }
```

But I am having trouble posting data to it. I am using the following jquery Ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ATOMWebService.svc/UpdateAnalysisParameters",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ parameterSets: "Dave" })
    });
```

But the web service is responding with "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The 
expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'."

How can I post json data to this web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the content type in your ajax request:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Setting the dataType only gives a hint to jquery about how to handle the received response.