# WCF request: "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, wcf

I try to call WCF service from ASPX page with AJAX.

I get the error: "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details."

Code is below.
(Without parameters request calling successfully!)

Service method:

```
[OperationContract]
[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string SimpleRequest(string fullname);
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="GenesysService.GenesysService">
    <endpoint address=""
 binding="webHttpBinding"
 contract="GenesysService.IGenesysService"
  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"> 
<identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment 
 multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

AJAX Request:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://localhost:56428/GenesysService.svc/SimpleRequest',
data: JSON.stringify({fullname: "fullname"}),
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,
success: function (response) {
    alert('success!');
    alert(response);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('error!');
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

I found the same [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804155/how-can-i-post-json-data-to-a-wcf-web-service). But then I add the next string:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

I get error: "OPTIONS <...> 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <...>. Invalid HTTP status code 405 "

Comment: don't see a need for "RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json" and JSON.stringify(

Answer (score 0):

The Method Not Allowed response in your Ajax call is due to the Javascript single origin policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

To call the service from your page it needs to be on the same port and protocol, or you can use JSONP.

More info here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Comment: I forgot to say what without parameters request calling successfully.